# Adding Dimension : Is it Axiom?

Tags: axioms, dimension-theory-analysis

Let's suppose I had one dimension defined as $D_1 =\{x \mid x \in \Bbb R\}$

then I will add another dimension to make $D_2 = \{(x,y)\mid x,y \in \Bbb R\}$

then I will generalize this adding one more dimension process and call it $F$ which keep add up another dimension to previous n-dimension.

Here my question is,

Could this process F be defined? or this process is an axiom that we just accept it?

Comment: It is a special case of the Cartesian Product of sets. I would say it is an axiom in set theory. The *dimension* comes when you consider this special example as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Gribouillis You would be wrong in saying that the existence of a cartesian product for sets is an axiom. The relevant axioms needed for the construction of binary and non-binary products of sets do not look immediately related to that, at first glance.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli could you provide more ground?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I found one definition of the cartesian product of sets in N.Bourbaki's theory of sets page 101. Actually, it is not presented as an axiom. I think it's necessary to read the 100 preceding pages to fully understand it. Also, this definition may be outdated because there is no mention of category theory for example.

Answer (score 1):

What you get is that $D_n = \mathbb R^n$ which is of dimension $n$. If we look at $\mathbb R^n$ as vector space, we can use basic facts from linear algebra:

1. Every vector space has a basis, i.e. linear independent set that spans whole vector space.
2. Any two bases of a vector space have same cardinality.

Cardinality, i.e. number of elements of basis is then called dimension. In the case of $\mathbb R^n$ it is $n$, as expected, because we can see that set $\{(1,0,\ldots,0),(0,1,\ldots,0),\ldots,(0,0,\ldots,1)\}$ is linearly independent and spans the whole space.

If you want to build $n+1$-dimensional vector space from $n$-dimensional, you can use that $\mathbb R^{n+1}\cong \mathbb R^n\times \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

The operation can be defined, and is usually called "taking the direct product with $\Bbb R$", with the notation $D_n\times \Bbb R=D_{n+1}$ (some purists might object to me using $=$ here, but for now that's not something you need to worry about).

Exactly how it's defined is dependent on what context you're in (are these sets, topological spaces, metric spaces, vector spaces, groups, rings, or something else?), but intuitively they all correspond to exactly what you do here: simply tacking on another coordinate at the end.

Comment: Under which axiomatical construction is availability of traking on another coordinate guaranteed?

Comment: That is such a broad question, I don't even know where to start (except answer "most of the ones which are in practical use; you don't need to worry about it"). Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: This queation is not for practicalness. I just want to anatomize the reason of dimensionality. The question is simple so I can barely think of any more specificities.

Comment: Think about order. Before I look into how people construct so called order from the aximatical object "empty set" I had never thought about and dissectes between definition and axiom. So I had started to question myself ": is this multiple dimensionality axiom? Or defintion?